# Simple- Remove comma from end of output of While Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, document.write

```
var i = 1;
while(i < 100){
       i *= 2;
       document.write(i + ", ");
}
```

So it writes:
 *2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128,*

What would the simplest way to take the comma off after it writes 128?

Comment: [You really shouldn't be using `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would the simplest way to take the comma off after it writes 128?

This simplest way to remove output is to **not** output it. One solution is to print the first value before the loop starts then write the comma before the value in the loop:

```
var i = 2;
document.write(i);
while(i < 99){
       i *= 2;
       document.write(", " + i);
}
```

Comment: @OpieT Alternatively, you leave your original `document.write()` but change the loop to stop 1 sooner and write the last element after the loop. The details are left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Do the comma as a prefix for everything but the first number

```
var i = 1; while(i < 100){
i *= 2;
document.write((i == 2 ? "" : ", ") + i);
}
```

So it writes:

2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128,

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you!